# how to get current minutes on PHP

Tags: php, time

I want to make a property to check the minutes a car has been parked for.

```
interface ControladorParquimetro{
    public function MinutosEstacionado($parked);
}

class parquimetro implements ControladorParquimetro{

    public function MinutesParked($parked){
        if (empty($parked)) {
            exit(0);
        } else{
            $minutes= date('s');
            set_time_limit($minutes);

            while ($i<=$minutes){
                echo $i;
                sleep(100);
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`$parked` returns the cars that are currently parked.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM car WHERE `parked` = 1";
$result= $conn->query($sql);
$result->fetch_assoc();

$parked= $result['time'];
```

I need to show this current time on screen.

Comment: is the $parked contains timestamp

Comment: Do You have any property that contains time when car start parking?

Comment: post your $parked data and explain properly what do you want

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM car WHERE `parked` = 1";
 $resultado = $conn->query($sql);
 $resultado->fetch_assoc();
$parked = $resultado['tiempo'];

Comment: $i is undefined in MinutesParked. If You want show current seconds just `echo $minutes`, current time: echo date('H:i:s')

Comment: If you only have an array with car IDs it'd be impossible to figure out how long someone has been parking there for. You need the current time and the time they parked to figure that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `strtotime()` with `date()`

```
if (empty($parked)) {
    exit(0);
} 
else{
    echo date('H:i:s',strtotime($parked));
}
```